# How to get preview tab from chrome.webRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I am currently building a chrome extension.
I want to access the preview tab of network section in devtools using the extension.
I am using chrome.webRequest API.

[preview tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnx8T.png)

However I am unable to find any information for the same.
Here is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Read js scripts",

    "icons": {
      "16": "images/globe.ico"
    },

    "background": {
        "service_worker": "content.js"
    },

      "permissions": [
        "webRequest"
      ],
      "host_permissions": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ]
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    console.log(details);
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"],types: ["script"]},
  ["extraHeaders", "responseHeaders"],
);
```

All that i get is this

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkMPB.png)

Any help would be appreciated.